# Need to change the color of a row depending on the status in ANGULAR 4

Tags: html, angular

I have 6 column ie.. name, email, phone, company, status_1 and status_2.

status_1 has two option , ie.. "1" or "0"
status_2 also has two option , ie.. "1" or "0"

My Requirement : I need to change the color of the row

logic :

```
    if(status_1 is "1" -> change to red)
    else if (status_2 is "1" -> change to green)
    else if (status_1 and status_2 is "1" -> give priority to status_1)
```

Mycode :

```
    <div>
      <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> E-Mail </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.email}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.phone}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company.name}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
    </div>
```

I will display 4 columns , and colour of the row should be changed according to status

please help me

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Make the following change

### html

change `mat-row` as

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getRowColor(row)}"></mat-row>
```

### ts

```
getRowColor(row){
  if (row.status_1 === '1') {
    return "red";
  } else if (row.status_2 === '1') {
    return "green";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[ngStyle]` to specify your conditions. Assuming the entire listing you gave is your row, add the directive to your outermost `<div>`, like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': status_1 === '1' ? 'red' : (status_2 === '1' ? 'green' : 'auto') }">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> E-Mail </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.email}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.phone}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

I would argue the expression should be in a function, which will be nicer to read and easier to maintain. Given

```
getColor() {
  if (status_1 === '1') {
    return 'red';
  } else if (status_2 === '1') {
    return 'green';
  }
}
```

You can change your `<div>` to use:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': getColor() }">
```

Comment: Thanks for the intimidate reply bro ! This answer is closely matching to me  . i need to put ngstyle instead of div to <matrow>. Thank u soo much bro.